# DesignAKnit shape (.shp) file format

Tags: disassembly, file-format

With help from information provided by members of this forum, I have more or less succeeded in reverse engineering DesignAKnit pattern (.stp) files. Has anybody worked on the shape files? I have never actually used them, but do have access to a copy of the Windows software, which I believe is written in some version of Pascal.

Comment: What is your question?